# Showing Office365 Ribbon/Bar Outside of SharePoint

Tags: javascript, azure, sharepoint, office365

Is it possible to include the Office 365 Ribbon/Bar outside of SharePoint? We've got the authentication working, but we need to show the bar for users as well.

Looking at what we are using on an existing version of the application running within SharePoint I have identified a few JS files that render the bar, but whenever I place them in a version of the application that runs outside SharePoint it doesn't seem to work. Is this because the Office Toolbar needs to be within a SharePoint master page to operate correctly?

It may be relevant that the site(s) will still sit on the Azure platform.